# Visual Studio 2005 cannot open .vbproj file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have an asp.net project developed in visual studio 2005. I created it on my machine, and then zipped the project and emailed it to the team lead to install the app on a central directory. However, when he double clicks on the .vbproj file (and if he attempts to open it using the 2005 IDE) he gets an error message:

> The project file
>   "C:\ImportOrderUpdate\ImportOrderUpdate\ImportOrderUpdate.vbproj"
>   cannot be opened. The project type is not supported by the installation.

What would be causing this issue?
Both machines have VS 2005 update versions.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you're missing the project type, either because he doesn't have VB installed, or [web application project](http://webproject.scottgu.com/) support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start out by assuming that the other computer has an equivalent version of Visual Studio installed, and that it works fine otherwise. If not, fix that first... In particular, make sure that "Visual Web Developer" is installed (re-run the installation and make sure that this feature is selected).

According to [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/06cf7bca-982c-44cf-aec9-99cf399b3000) in the MSDN forums, you might try running `devenv.exe /setup` from the command line (make sure you run the command line as Administrator):

> A few users have seen a situation
>   where when they try to create a .NET
>   Framework 3.0 project, they get a
>   package load failure for the
>   WPFFlavor.  This appears to be due to
>   having a machine that had earlier
>   versions of Visual Studio, .NET
>   Framework 3.0, and Visual Studio 2005
>   extensions for .NET Framework 3.0 (WCF
>   & WPF), November 2006 CTP.  If you hit
>   this problem, run "devenv /setup" from
>   the command line and this package load
>   failure should be resolved.

Also make sure that you've installed the [Update to Support Web Application Products](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=8B05EE00-9554-4733-8725-3CA89DD9BFCA&displaylang=en&siteID=TnL5HPStwNw-kgYx1jjPlrOR5AUIg9_OUw).

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual Basic .NET component to your Visual Studio to be able to open VB.NET projects